# (iOS) How can I get the UIViewController from a C++ Application?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I need to use a library in my C++ project that needs to call an extern function:

```
SetGameViewController(UIViewController* gameViewController)
```

I have zero knowledge of Objective C and iOS yet. I need to get UIViewController and pass it to that function.

So this code should get the UIViewController:

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;
```

I also added this import:

```
#if defined(OS_IPHONE)
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

I get compiler errors like:

```
Expected unqualified-id
Unknown type name 'NSString'
```

I've started learning Objective C and read a few articles but couldn't get much further than that yet.
So basically my question is how do I basically import and use Objective C code in C++ code so that I can get and use the UIViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way will be to rename your source file with the extension ".mm" - it will then be compiled as objective-c++, which means you get all the wonders of c++ while still being able to interact with objective-c objects (counted pointers to things 'derived' from NSObject).

Comment: Yeah, that's was it I figured that out already. Now the problem is how to tell the premake.exe utility that generates the xcode project to mark the .cpp file as objective c++ as this project needs to be compiled on windows too.

Comment: You'll need some conditional compilation magic since uiviewcontroller is not a windows thing. I use cmake, it handles objective-c++ perfectly well. In any case, clang will do the right thing based on the file extension

Comment: Our approach was to declare the function as "extern" and we are using premake to generate xcode project.